# Is it possible to trigger pipelines in GitLab with another file than the gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My use case :

- The first repo on my Gitlab server. I want to trigger pipelines using the standard gitlab-ci.yml file.
- A second repo, mirrored from the first repo, on another Gitlab instance. I want to trigger different pipelines, using a gitlab-ci-mirror.yml for example.

Can I tell the second Gitlab instance to use the gitlab-ci-mirror.yml for its pipelines? And not the gitlab-ci.yml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project settings, you can change the CI configuration path. This can be a file in the repository or you can even specify a file in another repository.

See [specify a custom CICD configuration file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#specify-a-custom-cicd-configuration-file) for more information.